# Generating Swagger Bearer Token Programmatically

Tags: swagger, bearer-token

I need to find a way to generate the bearer token on Swagger UI in order to call methods provided by an API through Swagger. The problem is the bearer token expires every x minutes and I have no other ways to update that token besides clicking the "Authorize" button on Swagger UI and copying the generated token into my code.

It's the exact same problem that this person encountered: 
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/How-to-generate-the-same-Bearer-token-as-Swagger/td-p/187638

As an end-user, is there a way for me to generate swagger bearer token programmatically?